# Como colocar barra de loading com Flutter Webview Plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

Implementei um navegador usando Flutter Webview Plugin (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin), no exemplo abaixo:

```
class _VisualizadorDeUrl extends StatelessWidget {
  final items;
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  _VisualizadorDeUrl(this.items);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text('Navegador'),
      ),
      hidden: true,
      url: items["link"],
      withZoom: false,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      scrollBar: true,
    );
  }
}
```

A String items contêm os endereços que quero abrir. Está funcionando normal.
O problema é que não mostra um CircularBarProgess quando o link é aberto. A página fica em branco até que seja carregado o site.

Tentei utilizar o:

```
initialChild: Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: const Center(
         child: new CircularProgressIndicator ();
        ),
      ),
```

No entanto, isso não muda simplesmente NADA no aplicativo, então removi pra deixar mais limpo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível implementar utilizando o callback `onPageFinished` presente na versão `0.3.5` em diante, junto com `Stack`.

Segue a implementação exemplo [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270264/7385033).